# pandas: group rows by repeated column values, keep max absolute value of each column in group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to reduce a pandas DataFrame with repeated datetime for some entries of `df['new_time']`, to a single row entry for each distinct `df['new_time']`.

Considering each group of repeated `new_time`, I want to keep the values that corresponds to the max (for the datetime `df.index`) or absolute max (for `df['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`) of each other column in the group.

So a DataFrame `df` like:

> ```
> import pandas as pd
> from datetime import datetime
> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[9, 7, 4, -2], 'B':[5, 6, -4, -5], 'C':[-5, -6, 7, -3],
>                   'D':[9, 2, 7, 8], 'new_time':[datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0),
>                   datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0), datetime(2000, 1, 1,0 ,1, 0),
>                   datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 10, 0)]}, 
>                   index=pd.date_range('20000101', freq='T', periods=4),
>                   )
> df.index.name = 'time'
> df
> ```
>
> Giving:
>
> ```
>                       A   B   C  D             new_time
> time
> 2000-01-01 00:00:00   9   5  -5  9  2000-01-01 00:04:00
> 2000-01-01 00:01:00   7   6  -6  2  2000-01-01 00:04:00
> 2000-01-01 00:02:00   4  -4   7  7  2000-01-01 00:01:00
> 2000-01-01 00:03:00  -2  -5  -3  8  2000-01-01 00:10:00
> ```

Should become (if sorted by `df['new_time']`):

> ```
>                       A   B   C  D             new_time
> time
> 2000-01-01 00:02:00   4  -4   7  7  2000-01-01 00:01:00
> 2000-01-01 00:01:00   9   6  -6  9  2000-01-01 00:04:00
> 2000-01-01 00:03:00  -2  -5  -3  8  2000-01-01 00:10:00
> ```

Note that the second row now contains value from the first two rows of the original `df`.

I've been trying along the lines of

`df.loc[df.groupby('new_time')['A'].idxmax()]`

or

`df.groupby('new_time').apply(lambda x: x[np.abs(x) == np.max(np.abs(x))])`

but I can't find a way to apply this to all columns, and particularly to deal with the need to apply `max()` to datetimes and `max(abs())` to the other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so easy:

```
#first create column from index for prevent losing
df1 = df.reset_index()
#select numeri and non numeric columns
cols1 = df1.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
cols2 = df1.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number]).columns
print (cols1)
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
print (cols2)
Index(['time', 'new_time'], dtype='object')

#create dictionaries for aggregation by types
d1 = {x:lambda x: x[x.abs().idxmax()] for x in cols1}
d2 = {x:lambda x: x.max() for x in cols2}
d = {**d1, **d2}

#aggregate, create index from time and reorder columns to original
df = df1.groupby('new_time').agg(d).set_index('time').reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
                     A  B  C  D            new_time
time                                               
2000-01-01 00:02:00  4 -4  7  7 2000-01-01 00:01:00
2000-01-01 00:01:00  9  6 -6  9 2000-01-01 00:04:00
2000-01-01 00:03:00 -2 -5 -3  8 2000-01-01 00:10:00
```

Comment: Thanks for this @jezrael, when I run  `cols1 = df1.select_dtypes(np.number).columns` or `cols2 = df1.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns`, I get the error:


`TypeError: include and exclude must both be non-string sequences`


I'm using numpy 1.13.1 and pandas 0.20.3, is this some behaviour that has changed?

Comment: Hard question, I use pandas `0.22.0` and numpy `1.12.1`. Maybe help `cols1 = df1.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
cols2 = df1.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number]).columns`

Comment: Got it in one :) If you update the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @WJB - Done ;) Thank you.